# Keypresses on Logitech wireless keyboard (Y-RH35) aren't detected on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, drivers

When I plug in a Logitech wireless keyboard, model `Y-RH35` into my Windows 7 machine, it installs the necessary drivers for the receiver, but the computer still doesn't receive the keypresses from the keyboard.

The keyboard works without issue on Linux.

How can I make the keyboard work on Windows 7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for the keypresses to be recognized, install [Logitech SetPoint](http://support.logitech.com/product/3131#download). This will also allow the use of the special buttons, such as the volume up/down and home buttons.